# Why some of WebResource.axd file for Telerik control does not load initially?

Tags: asp.net

I have some telerik controls on my page. When I run this page first time, some of WebResource.axd file does not load. It shows 404 Not Found Error. but when I refresh my page couple of times, the missing file comes and some other WebResource.axd shows 404 Not Found Error.
I checked httpHandlers in web.config, and it is correctly written.

Here is my screen clips:-

[image]

In other tab:-

[image]

After refreshing couple of times :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you combine and compress the Telerik javascripts in your master layout file? If so can you please share that piece of code?

It should be similar to;

```
Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
    .Scripts(scripts => scripts
    .AddGroup("CalendarGroup", group =>group
        .Add("telerik.common.min.js")
        .Add("telerik.calendar.min.js")
        .Add("telerik.datepicker.min.js")
        .Combined(true)
        .Compress(true)
```

You should add all the javascripts that's required by the Telerik controls that you use in your app.
(**Assumption** : Telerik MVC is being used)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Uchitha. but I am not using these codes in my web page, and My form is a simple web form, I am not using MVC. For compressing all the styles for telerik control, I have already used RadStyleSheetManager script tag. And it is working too, but the problem is that sometimes it does not load image (border, title) because even after compressing all the stylesheet it loads the image from resource file and that is the problem, some times  some of the resource file does not load.